# django HttpResponseRedirect will add '/' to the end of url

Tags: python, django

I am using django HttpResponseRedirect(url) to redirect the user to a new url, but I found this function will add a '/' to the end of url, which breaks my current design.

eg) some of urls is something like: /life/?ret=12344

If a '/' is appended, the url will be /life/?ret=12344/ which makes my prior code confused.

How to avoid adding '/' to the end?

Comment: Django is [smart enough](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/common.py#L88) not to do this. Are you sure there is no slash in `url`?

Comment: @DrTyrsa This is assuming `CommonMiddleware` is enabled and that the URL redirected to is `/life/?ret=12344`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that Django has `APPEND_SLASH` [option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash), So `APPEND_SLASH = False` should be helpful. But in case `/life/?ret=12344/` as mentioned @DrTyrsa django should be smart enough